# remaining variables of the data set

Tags: r, random, matrix

I have a data set of 150 numbers from which I sampled 100. 
How can I identify (put into a new matrix) the remaining 50?

```
X <- runif(150)
Combined <- sample(X, 100)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your code.

Answer (score 2):

Create your sample as a separate vector:

```
using <- sample(1:150, 100)

Entires <- All.Entries[using]
Non.Entries <- All.Entries[-using]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Update based on your comment.

If `Combined` is a subset of `X`, to find those elements of `X` that are not in `Combined` you can use:

```
    X[ !(X %in% Combined) ]
```

`X %in% Combined)`  will give you a logical vector of the same size as `X` of value `TRUE` when the element is in `Combined` and `FALSE` when the element is not.

as a course explanation: 
This logical vector can be used as indicies.  `X[  X %in% Combined ]` will give you all `X` such that `X` is in `Combined`.

Since you are seeking the opposite negate the logical vector `X[  !(X %in% Combined) ]` to get all `X` such that `X` is NOT in `Combined`.

---

**IF `X` contains duplicates** then you can filter based on names (assuming unique names of course)

```
X[ !(names(X) %in% names(Combined)) ] 

# or if sampling by rows
X[ !(rownames(X) %in% rownames(Combined)) ]
```

You can easily assign names to `X`

```
names(X) <- 1:length(X)

# or for multi-dimensional
rownames(X)  <- 1:nrow(X)
```

Also see the help docs for

```
?"%in%"  # note the quotes
?which
?match
```

---

Alternatively you can sample the indices instead, use the negative sign as follows `mat[-indices,]`
Example:

```
    # Create a sample matrix of 150 rows, 3 columns
    mat <- matrix(rnorm(450), ncol=3)

    # Take a sampling of indices to the rows
    indices <- sample(nrow(mat), 100, replace=F)

    # Splice the matrix
    mat.included <- mat[indices,]
    mat.leftover <- mat[-indices,]

    # Confirm everything is of proper size
    dim(mat)
    # [1] 150   3
    dim(mat.included)
    # [1] 100   3
    dim(mat.leftover)
    # [1] 50  3
```

Comment: I have a data set of 150 numbers so:
Combined=sample(x,100)
#Take 100 random numbers from dataset x

now how would I get the remaining 50 from x?

(I do not have much code to paste because I've been using the function 'duplicated' but it removes all duplicated numbers from the data set x

Answer (score 0):

All numbers:

```
x <- sample(10, 150, TRUE) # as an example
```

A random sample:

```
Combined <- sample(x,100)
```

The remaining numbers:

```
xs <- sort(x) # sort the values of x
tab <- table(match(Combined, xs))
Remaining <- xs[-unlist(mapply(function(x, y) seq(y, length = x),
                               tab, as.numeric(names(tab))))]
```

Note. This solution also works if `x` has duplicated values.

Comment: what is the y variable here?Thank you very much

Comment: @user1816762 The variable `y` is the third argument of the `mapply` function, namely `as.numeric(names(tab))`. This numeric vector indicates the positions in `xs` where the values of `Combined` are found.